# Пунктуация. Запутался я, нужны запятые или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот про хлебушек(,) в дневнике у тебя(,) вообще грустная запись.

Answer (score 3):

Вот про хлебушек в дневнике у тебя вообще грустная запись.

Для постановки запятой после *хлебушек* нет, по-моему, никаких оснований. После *у тебя* **можно** поставить авторское тире. ***А лучше написать ваше предложение без запятых и тире, так как запятые и тире в нём не нужны.***

Comment: Согласен, для постановки запятых нет никаких оснований. Авторское тире можно поставить, но лучше не ставить.

Answer (score 1):

Нужны. Очень хорошие запятые. Они обособляют уточнение, где именно запись про хлебушек.

Главное редакторское правило: не трогай того (авторского), чего можно не трогать. А я просто-таки слышу эти запятые.

А вот тире никакого нам не надоть.

Comment: Уточнение от широкого к узкому. А здесь определение и обстоятельство. Разные члены предложения. А если автору захотелось везде везде, где ему вздумается, ставить запятые, вы тоже не будете исправлять?

Comment: >> *Главное редакторское правило: не трогай того (авторского), чего можно не трогать.* Галина, а в вашей редакторской практике чего больше: лишних запятых или недостающих? ))

Comment: Скорее лишних. Но если они хоть каким-то сотым подпунктом правила допускаются, ни-ни!